# Display json into html table with angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I'm having problems deploying a json reponse on a table,
This is my controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
$scope.jsonData = {};
```

This is the function inside my controler.js where I post data and my php response with my table content

```
$scope.continue = function(choices)
{
var json = $scope.choices;

$http.post('php/calculador.php', json)
 .then(function(response) {

    $scope.jsonData = response;
    console.log($scope.jsonData);

});


};
});
```

I printed the json data in console to be sure the data is correct, and it is, but it does not display any data in my html table

this is my HTML table 
Where I'm trying to deploy my json

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in jsonData">
<td>{{ x.costo_m }}</td>
<td>{{ x.desc }}</td>
<td>{{ x.id }}</td>
</tr>
```

This is printed on console

```
Object
data:Array[1]
   0: Array[1]
      0: Object
        costo_m: 18.973529411765
        desc: "BLONG-F25+MOBICTRL"
        id: "choice1"
        licencias: 4.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jsonData` is not an array, it's an object which seems to have a single property `data`, which then contains an array of arrays. The inner array seems to be what you want, though.

So, just replace `$scope.jsonData = response;` with `$scope.jsonData = response.data[0];`

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to post that I already try that, didnt work :(

Comment: My bad. I looked again and it actually seems that `response.data` is not an array, but an array of arrays. I don't know much about the data itself but it seems that you need `response.data[0]` instead. Tell me if this is right and I'll update my answer.